# Computed variable return self if exists or new instance if nil

Tags: ios, swift, computed-properties

If I have a `ScoreModel` for my app that I need to pass to the next `UIViewController`. It may not exist and thus not passed to this new `UIViewController`. If this is the case I would like to have it create a new instance of the Model. This won't work (endless loop) but it will give the idea of what i'm trying to create:

```
var scoreModel : ScoreModel! {
    get {
        if self.scoreModel == nil {
            return ScoreModel()
        } else {
            return self.scoreModel
        }
    }
    set {
        self.scoreModel = newValue
    }
}
```

How can I check if the current version of `scoreModel == nil` without getting in a loop?

Comment: Sounds like you want a lazy var. Read up here: http://alisoftware.github.io/swift/2016/02/28/being-lazy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if, instead of trying to mess around with custom getters/setters, you just made your scoreModel property optional (better convention anyway) and when you want to pass it to the next view controller you check if its nil. Something like this:

```
var scoreModel: ScoreModel?
let nextViewController = UIViewController()
nextViewController.scoreModel = scoreModel ?? ScoreModel()
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are talking about a lazy initialized variable

```
lazy var scoreModel = ScoreModel()
```

The initializer is called when the variable is accessed the first time.

Comment: Yeah but I wanted to know if it hasn't been passed yet by a previous ViewController before creating it :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lazy var like this:

```
class Test {


   lazy var scoreModel: ScoreModel = {
        return ScoreModel()
    }()

}

let test = Test()
test.scoreModel = ScoreModel()
```

Comment: Wouldnt this create a new instance?